# Different endings of Yishtabach

Tags: sources-mekorot, blessing, prayer-book, nuschaot, pesukei-dezimra

There are at least five *nuschaos* (liturgies) for the very end of *Yishtabach* between *habocheir b'shirei zimrah* (who chooses musical songs of praise) and *chai/chei** *haolamim* (life/life-giver of the world):†

1. הַבּוֹחֵר בְּשִׁירֵי זִמְרָה חֵי הָעוֹלָמִים ( – nothing – )
2. הַבּוחֵר בְּשִׁירֵי זִמְרָה **מֶלֶךְ** חֵי הָעוֹלָמִים (***God***)
3. הַבּוחֵר בְּשִׁירֵי זִמְרָה **מֶלֶךְ אֵל** חֵי הָעוֹלָמִים (***King, God***)
4. הַבּוחֵר בְּשִׁירֵי זִמְרָה **מֶלֶךְ יָחִיד** חֵי הָעוֹלָמִים (***unique King***)
5. הַבּוחֵר בְּשִׁירֵי זִמְרָה **מֶלֶךְ יָחִיד אֵל** חֵי הָעוֹלָמִים (***unique King, God***)

What is the reason (and source) for each version?

---

<sup>* The *nikkud* of *ches* varies, but is not the subject of this question. The examples are vowelized solely for readability.

† Punctuation has been removed from the examples to further lessen variation that is not the subject of this question.</sup>

1. E.g. [*Teimani Baladi* (Yemen)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31800/does-anyone-pray-according-to-rambams-seder-tefila#comment138790_31829).
2. E.g. [Sephardim as brought by the Minchas Elazar](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4735&st=&pgnum=13&hilite=).
3. E.g. [*Ashkenaz* (German)](http://opensiddur.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Siddur-Sefas-Yisroel-v.1.15-10.-Pesukei-DZimro-Yishtabach.pdf), [*Adot ha-Mizrach* (Sephardic)](http://www.shtaygen.com/?CategoryID=1316&ArticleID=4428&Page=1), [*Munkacz* (Chassidic)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4735&st=&pgnum=13&hilite=).
4. E.g. [*Chabad* (Lubavitch)](http://www.chabad.org/library/siddur/default_cdo/aid/1495868/jewish/Siddur.htm#!/aid:1524188/title:Yishtabach%20-%20%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%99%20%D7%93%D7%96%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%94), *Lev Tahor* (Chassidic)
5. E.g. Common *Sfard* (Chassidic).

Comment: Re: _Nusach Teiman_: There are at least two Yemenite _Nuscha'ot_, _Baladi_ and _Shami_, and only the _Baladi_ (somewhat) follows the Rambam's _Nusach_ (the _Shami_ is more Sephardic). A link for a _Baladi_ Yemenite _Nusach_: http://www.shtaygen.com/?CategoryID=1316&ArticleID=4427. Also, somewhat related: [Why does Mishneh Torah have Shem uMalchut for Yishtabach?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35941/1368).

Comment: @TamirEvan I added Baladi specification. Do you happen to know how Shami ends Yishtabach?

Comment: @nbz shaami most likely ends in the safaradi/eiduth ha mizrah nosah for they switched from original to theirs. mori qafih says rambam zl used the tiklal for the nosah of his seifar ha tafillo in the back of seifar ahavo. i forgot what reasoning he gave for the changes in few words.

Comment: There is yet a 5th nusach from the sephardim. see מאמר נוסח התפלה סי' יג: 
"מלך חי העולמים"

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4735&st=&pgnum=13&hilite=

Comment: @user6781 Thank you. Added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was only able to find a solutions to some issues you raised.

Answer based on the [סידור רבינו הזקן עם ציונים והערות](https://hebrewbooks.org/30450) (picture below) and [מאמר נוסח התפלה סי' יג](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4735&st=&pgnum=13&hilite=):

**Why do we say א-ל חי (nusach 3 and 5)?**

See Shaeri Orah from רבינו יוסף גיקיטיליא who writes (printed in מאמר נוסח התפלה):

> וכל הרוצה לבקש חיים טובים יתכוין למדת א"ל ח"י: Whoever wants to request good life should concentrate to the A-l Chay Attribute.

**Why only מלך יחיד (nusach chabad)?**

See for example [Torah Or 40:3](https://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/toraor/10/40c.htm), which explains that מלך יחיד is not the regular way how מלכות comes to create  the world rather how it is connected to it's source in אא"ס - יחיד. (more sources qouted in סידור רבינו הזקן עם ציונים והערות

> ומלך יחיד חי העולמים היינו שלהיות חי העולמים הוא מתצמצם בבחי' מלך
> ובחינת מלך זה הגם שהוא בחי' אחרונה לגבי א"ס ב"ה עצמו מ"מ הוא בבחי'
> יחיד ומיוחד קדוש ומובדל כו' לגבי התהוות עלמין ואי לזאת נמשך בחינת
> מלכותו לבחי' יחיד חי העולמים להיות התלבשות מלך יחיד קדוש ומובדל כו'
> בבחינת עלמין והיינו בעוה"ז הגשמי דוקא כי נעוץ תחלתן בסופן דייקא

[image]
[image]